# Ultra-fast load switch

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, pcb, nmos, capacitive

I have a question that I am assuming has a very easy answer (hopefully). I am trying to turn on and off the power to a pcb really fast, on the order of 1us. My problem is that my board has some bypass caps which slow my rise and fall time of my switch, on the order of 1ms. I am using a simple NMOS switch with the part FDBL0090N40. My mosfet in my simulation is similar and was already in the LTspice library, and the 10uF load represents my board.

[image: Simple Switch]

My thought is that when gate voltage is applied, there is a ground path to quickly dump the 10uF load, as seen in the fast discharge of the blue trace. Now, I was thinking that the 22uF would provide the charging transient current to give a quicker charge. The caps have a 50m ESR. I guess I could try a push pull configuration, but I was hoping that this simple implementation would work. The 22uF are those spot welded stacked ceramic caps that I have in my collection. I didn't want the high ESR of electrolytics.

Thank you

Comment: What's the purpose of the 10k resistor? That's going to limit how quickly you can charge the capacitors.

Comment: (Also note that you're not driving that MOSFET fully on. But that's not really a problem here, as you're trying to waste energy and it's all in a single big pulse, so efficiency and heating aren't a concern.)

Comment: If you decide to go with a push pull, just be sure that your pcb is designed to handle (near) grounding the positive (I assume) power rail. Some circuits do not appreciate current flowing backward.

Comment: To what end? If the board was apparently made to sustain itself for some milliseconds (power disconnected), are you trying to shut it down faster than that? Is that a good thing? Should its outputs be gated instead? Related, is this a power glitching procedure? (That usually involves partial, not complete, shutdown, however.)

Comment: Just do a push-pull configuration.

Comment: @TimWilliams. You are correct, this is for power glitching to test effects on a chip

Comment: @Hearth, I tried different values for that resistor. I was thinking it was a bleeder resistor.

Comment: @user253751 Would I not have the same issue with a push pull? I can see that the load capacitor would discharge through PMOS, but when the top of the push pull is open, wouldn't I have effectively the same circuit?

Comment: @Frank When you turn the FET off, the reason it doesn't return to full voltage instantly is that you have an RC circuit going on there (a complex one, but still going to delay turn-on). If you want to return to full voltage quickly, you should use a half-bridge instead of a single FET.

Comment: @Hearth I see, that makes sense. I will try that

Comment: @Frank When you turned the top MOSFET on (whether it's N or P) you would have a low resistance path from the power supply to the board which would charge it quickly.

Comment: @Frank Oh, then that's a heck of a lot easier: one, amplitude likely doesn't need to be full supply; and two, these's standard hardware for that. If nothing else, the desired equivalent circuit is simply a bias tee: a series inductor or resistor between DC source and DUT, and a coupling capacitor between signal source and DUT. The source in this case shall be a low impedance (whatever the DUT requires as source maximum impedance, or less), which can be done with a voltage divider and/or beefy MOSFETs. Finally, use a half-bridge circuit to get symmetrical drive.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hey Tim, thank you for the input. I actually can't believe that I didn't view it this way. I don't need to turn on and off the supply, I just need to push the rail down. And as you said, it doesn't need to go to 0. I see now that there is a device called a chipwhisperer that does this.